# How safe it is to run the magento cron.php cron job every minute?

Tags: cron, order-email

About Magento 1.9

I want to run Magento's cron.php every minute because, I want sales email to be sent the soonest possible on client order. So besides the email function can someone let me know what the default cron.php does in the sense how wise it is to run it every minute, and if we do run it every minute what to be aware of before 1 minute becomes a problem for these jobs.

Answer (score 8):

Completely safe - and in most cases mandatory, otherwise jobs can end up being skipped.

Just make sure you are executing `cron.sh` not `cron.php`

Just note that the regularity of the cron itself won't dictate when cron operations take place - the module itself does that.

Eg. Using the awesome [MageRun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) to list tasks,

```
[www-data@acc1 .microcloud ~]
[~]$ mr_examplecom sys:cron:list


  Cronjob List


+-----------------------------------------+------+----+----+----+----+
| Job                                     | m    | h  | D  | M  | WD |
+-----------------------------------------+------+----+----+----+----+
| aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_coupons_data     | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_invoiced_data    | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_order_data       | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_refunded_data    | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_shipment_data    | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_tax_data         | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| captcha_delete_expired_images           | */10 | *  | *  | *  | *  |
| captcha_delete_old_attempts             | */30 | *  | *  | *  | *  |
| catalog_product_alert                   |      |    |    |    |    |
| catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all | 0    | 2  | *  | *  | *  |
| catalogrule_apply_all                   | 0    | 1  | *  | *  | *  |
| core_clean_cache                        | 30   | 2  | *  | *  | *  |
| currency_rates_update                   |      |    |    |    |    |
| log_clean                               |      |    |    |    |    |
| newsletter_send_all                     | */5  | *  | *  | *  | *  |
| paypal_fetch_settlement_reports         |      |    |    |    |    |
| persistent_clear_expired                | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| sales_clean_quotes                      | 0    | 0  | *  | *  | *  |
| sitemap_generate                        |      |    |    |    |    |
| system_backup                           |      |    |    |    |    |
| xmlconnect_notification_send_all        | */5  | *  | *  | *  | *  |
+-----------------------------------------+------+----+----+----+----+
```

You can see that amongst the tasks, the most regular in this list is every 5 minutes. Which means that even if the cron were to be configured to run every minute, it wouldn't make a difference, as `newsletter_send_all` and `xmlconnect_notification_send_all` would only run every 5 minutes.

---

If CLI isn't your bag, then you can use (the equally awesome) [Aoe Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) to visualise the timeline.

This will let you see when tasks are due to run, and if they are being executed or skipped.

Comment: Why cron.sh over cron.php?

Comment: cron.sh makes sure that only one instance of the script runs at the time

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that if you don't have Magento cron running as regularly as the most frequently running job, depending on your cron timings you can also get 2 instances of the same job running at the same time and this can cause problems.  So I would agree with Ben, having it run every minute is the best idea then you know this situation can never occur.

Comment: @Jonathan Hussey: As far as I know all jobs are executed sequentially. So when you run the scheduler with cron.sh you should be fine. Isn't it?